# Cross-Origin Read Block While Serving Image

Tags: php, cross-origin-read-blocking

First of all, I'm sorry for my bad English.

I prepared a florist script with PHP. I save the images in the images folder in the management panel and fetch the images as follows:

```php
<img src="<?= $admin_url; ?>images/products/image.jpg">
```

When I did it this way, I kept getting the following error: Cross-Origin Read Blocking.
Ben de şöyle değiştirdim:

```php
<img src="<?php echo $admin_url; ?>images/products/image.jpg">
```

Actually, I thought the problem was solved because I could see the pictures and the site was working. After a while it started giving the same error again. So this time I changed it like this:

```php
<img src="https://adminpanel.com/images/products/image.jpg">
```

This time, like the previous one, it got better for a while, then it broke down again and now it's like this and it's not working either. As I said, it gives CORB error and I cannot see the images I uploaded to my site.

In short, I couldn't fix it no matter what I did and this situation was really starting to bother me. Can you help me, please?

The exact code I'm trying to take pictures of is now as follows:

```php
$getProducts = getProductsIndex();
foreach($getProducts as $a) {
   $product_id = $a['id'];
   $getImageQuery = $db -> query("SELECT * FROM product_imgs WHERE product = '$product_id' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
   $getImage = $getImageQuery -> fetch();
   echo '<div class="shop-item col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
   <div class="inner-box">
   <div class="image">
   <a href="urun?value=' . encrypt($product_id) . '" style="display: inline-block; width: 305px; height: 285px;"><img src="https://admin.seydisehircicekci.com/images/products/' . $getImage['img'] . '" alt="Ürün Görseli" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" /></a>
   </div>
   <div class="lower-content">
   <h6><a href="urun?value=' . encrypt($product_id) . '">' . $a['name'] . '</a></h6>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
   <div class="price">₺ ' . $a['price'] . '</div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>
   </div>';
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone who helps!

I was trying to fetch images from the admin panel to my website but I encountered the CORB error many times and could not fetch in the images.

I still can't solve the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: I presume admin domain is different than main domain? You likely need `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` depending on how content is being served the addition of that will vary, PHP, nginx, apache, something else...You also are open to SQL injections, use prepared statements and parameterize queries.

Comment: Hello @user3783243, thank you for answering.
My admin domain and main domain are not different. One is domain.com, the other is admin.domain.com. I will fix my SQL injection errors, thanks. But I need to solve this problem first.

Comment: _"My admin domain and main domain are not different. One is domain.com, the other is admin.domain.com."_ - those _are_ different host names, and therefor also different origins.

Comment: `admin.seydisehircicekci.com` doesn't seem to resolve for me, via public DNS. Is this something you have set up only locally?